# How to call a global string variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following global variable:

```
Option Explicit

Public locationCode As String                               'Access the locationCode on the form anywhere on the project

Public Sub Settings()

'Declaration to access the data entered in the
'locationCode from anywhere on the project

locationCode = frmEnterLocation.txtLocationCode.Value


End Sub
```

But when I try to use my variable on another part of the project for example here:

```
Private Sub cmdOKButton_Click()


frmEnterLocation.txtLocationCode.SetFocus


If locationCode = "" Then

    MsgBox "You have not entered a Location Code", vbCritical, "Please Enter a Location Code"


           frmEnterLocation.txtLocationCode.SetFocus

Else

     Unload Me

End Sub
```

The variable is not storing the value from the text box.  How can I properly call this property on my Sub?

Comment: Posted a solution to assign the value from the text box to a given global variable via text box change event and added some improvements to your code (e.g. resetting old value after user exiting or correcting failing `SetFocus` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assign value from text box via text box Change Event in Form code module**

You have to assign the text box value after each change in text box txtLocationCode from *within the user form* to get it stored:

```
Private Sub txtLocationCode_Change()
' assign new value to global variable after each change in text box txtLocationCode
  locationCode = Me.txtLocationCode.Value
End Sub
```

**Calling the Userform from a Standard code module**

To make your settings you just show an instance of the userform after global declaration of your `locationCode` and a variable that restores the old value after user abortion via red [x] (see the last section below `Sub UserForm_QueryClose`).

```
Option Explicit     ' declaration head of a standard code module

' Access the locationCode on the form anywhere on the project
  Public locationCode    As String                               
  Public locationCodeOld As String

Sub Settings()
  With New frmEnterLocation
      .Show vbModeless
  End With
End Sub
```

*Note:* The `With New ..` statement allows you to unload (destroy) the called userform instance properly.

**Complete Userform code module (without `UserForm_QueryClose` -> see below)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub txtLocationCode_Change()  ' << as discussed above
' assign new value to global variable after each change in text box txtLocationCode
  locationCode = Me.txtLocationCode.Value
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOKButton_Click()
' SetFocus isn't executed after MsgBox, so use a Label1 info
If locationCode = "" Then
   Me.Caption = "No Location Code entry yet"
   Me.Label1.Caption = "Please Enter a Location Code"
   Me.txtLocationCode.SetFocus
Else
   Me.Caption = "Location code is " & locationCode
   Me.Label1.Caption = "Location Code"
   Me.Hide
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
' remember old setting of locationCode
  locationCodeOld = locationCode
' display current setting in text box and headers
  Me.txtLocationCode.Value = locationCode
  Me.txtLocationCode.SetFocus
  Me.Caption = "Location code is " & IIf(Len(locationCode) = 0, " not yet entered", locationCode)
  Me.Label1.Caption = IIf(Len(locationCode) = 0, "Please enter ", "") & "Location Code"
End Sub
```

**Recommended Addition to userform code module**

This allows you to restore the old value after user abortion via red [x]:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
' Reset old locationcode if form is aborted by user via [x}
If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    locationCode = locationCodeOld
    locationCodeOld = ""
    Me.Hide
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `Public locationCode As String` in the Declarations area (i.e. at the top) of a standard public module code sheet, not a private worksheet code sheet.